# Getting an undefined method error after finding record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So here's the situation. There's a table called Course. And a Course can have many GA's (graduate assistants).

I find a specific course like this:

```
this_course = Course.where("name = 'COMP1900'")
```

Then I try to test if they have any GA's currently assigned to them (this works elsewhere in code):

```
if this_course.gas.empty?
```

So this throws an undefined method error though. How come? Using .gas.empty? elsewhere seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

It should be like : `this_course = Course.where("name = 'COMP1900'").first`
As `where` clause returns an array object.

Answer (score 1):

`where` gives you an **array** of objects that meet the conditions you pass in as the argument.

In your case, let's say there are **3** items that satisfy your condition of `Course.where("name = 'COMP1900'")`.

Then, `this_course` will look like this:

`this_course = [Object_1, Object_2, Object_3]`

**Since `this_course` is an array**, **even if `gas` is an attribute of `Course`, it's not an attribute or a method of the array, so it will give you an error.**

You can fix this by grabbing the first element that meets this condition:

`this_course = Course.where("name = 'COMP1900'").first`

or you can alternatively do something like:
`this_course = Course.find_by(name: 'COMP1900')` which will also return the first element.